Shimano Dynamo DH-3N31-NH broken lead wire
The lead wire broke between the coil and the connector. The repair joint must fit into the axle groove. I have failed X2 to mend it. Can the lead be repaired at the coil?

Add some pictures to show exactly where it broke. One of the things about this question is that even among the fairly small subset of people who have made this kind of fix or otherwise taken apart Shimano gen hubs, we're not necessarily going to just know how they're all put together internally in terms of where in each model you could successfully locate the wire splices/repairs that will need to happen. I've overhauled 3N71/72 a few times but what you have may be laid out differently.
